# Manter o hover em um botão apos tirar o mouse

Tags: javascript, html, css

Como manter o efeito do hover após tirar o mouse do botão?
O código abaixo tem essa função, mas apenas ao clicar, eu sou bem novo nisso, mas estou aprendendo.

```js
var header = document.getElementById("div777");
var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("botao");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("ativo");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" ativo", "");
    this.className += " ativo";
  });
}
```

```css
.botao {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 10px 16px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.ativo, .botao:hover {
    background-color: #666;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="div777">
  <a class="botao">1</a>
  <a class="botao ativo">2</a>
  <a class="botao">3</a>
  <a class="botao">4</a>
  <a class="botao">5</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mude nessa linha `btns[i].addEventListener("click", function()` troque o `"click"` por `"mouseover"`

```js
var header = document.getElementById("div777");
var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("botao");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("ativo");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" ativo", "");
    this.className += " ativo";
  });
}
```

```css
.botao {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 10px 16px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.ativo, .botao:hover {
    background-color: #666;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="div777">
  <a class="botao">1</a>
  <a class="botao ativo">2</a>
  <a class="botao">3</a>
  <a class="botao">4</a>
  <a class="botao">5</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema já foi explicado na outra resposta, que lhe sugere trocar o evento `click` por `mouseover`. Se você quer que algo acontece quando passa o rato então tem mesmo de ser o evento `mouseover`. Desta forma cada vez que passa o mouse por cima do elemento, ele troca o classe `ativo` de forma permanente, e por isso mesmo que tire o mouse por cima de todos os elementos, a classe mantem-se.

No entanto o código de colocar e retirar a classe `ativo` está mais complicado do que devia. Se consultar a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) irá ver que cada elemento tem uma propriedade `classList` que permite modificar a lista de classes de uma forma simples. Os métodos relevantes para o problema são:

- `classList.add` - Adiciona mais uma classe ao elemento
- `classList.remove` - Retira a classe indicada da lista de classes do elemento

Utilizando isto o código que vem dentro do evento ficaria assim:

```
btns[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("ativo")[0]; //apanhar o ativo
    current.classList.remove("ativo"); //remover a classe nele
    this.classList.add("ativo"); //adicionar a classe ativo naquele onde tem o mouse
});
```

As duas buscas iniciais de elementos ao html, também podem ser simplificadas numa só utilizando [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) forçando que apanhe apenas elementos da classe `botao` dentro do `div777`:

```
var btns = document.querySelectorAll("#div777 .botao");
```

Exemplo com tudo o que foi mencionado:

```js
var btns = document.querySelectorAll("#div777 .botao");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("ativo")[0];
    current.classList.remove("ativo");
    this.classList.add("ativo");
  });
}
```

```css
.botao {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 10px 16px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.ativo, .botao:hover {
    background-color: #666;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="div777">
  <a class="botao">1</a>
  <a class="botao ativo">2</a>
  <a class="botao">3</a>
  <a class="botao">4</a>
  <a class="botao">5</a>
</div>
```